# Swift: unable to sort an Array of jsonDecoder

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4, xcode9

I am trying to parse json object using `jsonDecoder.decode`

Here is my code:

```
let myData = try jsonDecoder.decode([ZXYY].self, from: data! )
```

Everything works just fine but the problem is that need to sort the array by dates.

Im trying to do that with the following code:

```
var data = myData.sorted{ ($0["date"])! > ($1["date"] )! }
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Type 'ZXYY' has no subscript members
```

Any of you knows how can fix this error or a work around?

Help would be much appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `self`? did you mean `$0.date > $1.date`?

Comment: @Larme, can you please explain your question?

Comment: `myData` is an array of `ZXYY` objects, right? `ZXYY` has a property `date`, no? So in the `sorted()`, `$0` and `$1` is a `ZXYY` object. Why should you do myZXYYObject["date"] then? No, you just do `myZXYYObject.date`. So just do `$0.date > $1.date`.

Comment: The problem is not getting the object by key. The problem is doesn't recognize this values $0 or $1

Comment: If the error is really `Type 'ZXYY' has no subscript members`, then it knows that $0 and $1 are object of type `ZXYY`.

Comment: @Larme Ok..But how can make this code works `var data = myData.sorted{ ($0["date"])! > ($1["date"] )! }` ? it works with an array of dictionary  dates

Comment: `var data = myData.sorted{ ($0["date"])! > ($1["date"] )! }`: That code shouldn't work with an array of dates. It should work with an array of dictionary which have a key "date". `var data = myData.sorted({$0.date > $1.date})` doesn't work?